# How to create animation video for android

Tags: android, graphics, android-animation

I want to create animation video for android splash screen .
I have an icon and want to apply animation for my icon . So now i want to know how to animated my icon and which tools i can use for making animated video. Plz ans. Advanced Thanks.

Comment: are you searching for this http://javatechig.com/android/creating-frame-animations-in-android

Answer (score 2):

There are different types of animation:

- Frame animation: similar to what you see in animated cartoons. Each frame is a separate picture. A sequence of pictures will be played consequentially in order to create an animation. This animation can be done in android like [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html).
- Property animation: This is when you have a static image, but you want to move it around, scale it, or rotate it and etc. There are two ways to do this in android: [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html).

Answer (score 1):

To get a clear high class animation you can use tools like c4d r after effects but see thought it your app like will not consume because of it. if you use it  its user your app will a quality because of this animation.

peace,.